# Conditional where statement involving multiple columns in same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables

**Table1:**

```
emp_id, code_1, code_2
```

**Table2:**

```
code_1, code_2
```

**Table3:**

```
emp_id, emp_ind
```

**Table2** is a lookup table. I need to update **Table3** checking `code_1` and `code_2` of **Table1** present in **Table2**.

If `code_2` in **Table2** is `null`, then check if `code_1` in **Table1** and **Table2** match, if `yes` update `emp_ind` in **Table3** as `Y`.

If `code_1` in **Table2** is `null`, then check if `code_2` in **Table1** and **Table2** match, if `yes` update `emp_ind` in **Table3** as `Y`.

If `code_1` and `code_2` both are valued in **Table2**, check if both `code1` and `code2` in **Table1** match with that of **Table2**, if `yes` update `emp_ind` in **Table3**.

Is there a way to do it simply instead of checking like below:

```
Update table_3 t3
Set t3.emp_ind = 'Y'
Where exists (
    Select 1 from table1 t1
        Inner Join table2 t2 
        on t1.code_1 = t2.code_1
        Where t2.code_2 is null
        And t2.emp_id= t3.emp_id
    Union
    Select 1 from table1 t1
        Inner Join table2 t2 
        on t1.code_2 = t2.code_2
        Where t2.code_1 is null
        And t2.emp_id= t3.emp_id
    Union
    Select 1 from table1 t1
        Inner Join table2 t2 
        on t1.code_1 = t2.code_1
        And t1.code_2 = t2.code_2
        Where t2.emp_id= t3.emp_id
)
```

Comment: A [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression and [`is null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should let you use a pair of `left outer join`s between `Table1` and `Table2` on `code_1` and `code_2` to determine the `emp_ind` values for `Table3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the conditional joins using `OR` operator like this:

```
Update table_3 t3
Set t3.emp_ind = 'Y'
Where exists (
    Select 1 from table1 t1
        Inner Join table2 t2 
        on 
           (t1.code_1 = t2.code_1 AND t2.code_2 is null)
        OR (t1.code_2 = t2.code_2 AND t2.code_1 is null)
        OR (t1.code_1 = t2.code_1 AND t1.code_2 = t2.code_2)
        Where t2.emp_id= t3.emp_id
)
```